# Cannot install Aptana Studio 3 on Eclipse 3.7, Elementary OS Luna

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

cannot install Aptana Studio 3 on Eclipse 3.7, Elementary OS Luna. I get the following errors:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C)
Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.100.v20120522-1841 (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.100.v20120522-1841)
Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.0.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.0.dist)
Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.200.v20130402-1505 (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.200.v20130402-1505)
Common Eclipse Runtime 3.6.0.v20110523 (org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.6.0.v20110523)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Aptana Studio 3 Core 3.6.0.1402537589-B27k88Bma9kxYA5ZR9833355984B (com.aptana.feature.feature.group 3.6.0.1402537589-B27k88Bma9kxYA5ZR9833355984B)
To: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.6.0.201407100643-7f7D37k6bPlkbrRb8WuT8t_CCL4C)
To: com.aptana.feature.feature.group [3.6.0.1402537589-B27k88Bma9kxYA5ZR9833355984B]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Core Runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025)
To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.100,4.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Core Runtime 3.9.100.v20131218-1515 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.9.100.v20131218-1515)
To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.100,4.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse CSS SWT Theme Support 0.9.100.v20130515-1857 (org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.9.100.v20130515-1857)
To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse CSS SWT Theme Support 0.9.4.v20130123-162658 (org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.9.4.v20130123-162658)
To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH)
To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-8R9GFpOFUdy-521934]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse RCP 3.7.2.dist-8R9GFpOFUdy-521934 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.7.2.dist-8R9GFpOFUdy-521934)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.6.0.dist]
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

copy http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

From the Help menu, select Install New Software... to open the Install New Software dialog.
Paste the URL for the update site into the Work With text box, and hit the Enter (or Return) key.
In the populated table below, check the box next to the name of the plug-in, and then click the Next button.
Click the Next button to go to the license page.
Choose the option to accept the terms of the license agreement, and click the Finish button.
You may need to restart Eclipse to continue.